# instafeed.js: The access_token provided is invalid

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, instagram-api

Is anyone else experiencing issues with their Instagram feed using [instafeed.js](http://instafeedjs.com)?

I've been getting the getting the following javascript console error since about 5 days ago, which was perviously working fine.

> Uncaught Error: Error from Instagram: The access_token provided is invalid

This is my code:

```
if ($('#instafeed').length == 1) {
    var feed = new Instafeed({
        get: 'user',
        userId: USER_ID,
        clientId: 'CLIENT_ID',
        template: '<div class="columns small-6 medium-4 large-3"><div class="instagram-image-wraper"><a class="test" href="{{link}}"><img src="{{image}}" /></a></div></div>',
        resolution: 'low_resolution',
        limit: 12,
    });
    feed.run();
}
```

I'm unsure if this is related to the platform policy updates that were mentioned a few days ago - http://developers.instagram.com/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Instagram has changed their policy and instafeed.js requires access token now.

You can create an access token with this [site](http://instagram.pixelunion.net/).

After creating an access token, you can use instafeed.js like this:

```
var feed = new Instafeed({
    get: 'user',
    userId: 'UserID',
    clientId: 'ClientID',
    accessToken:'AccessTokenInHere',
    resolution: 'low_resolution',
    template: '<div class="columns small-6 medium-4 large-3"><div class="instagram-image-wraper"><a class="test" href="{{link}}"><img src="{{image}}" /></a></div></div>',
    limit: 12,
    });
```

Comment: This will be nothing more than a temporary solution - https://github.com/stevenschobert/instafeed.js/issues/408

Comment: If you suggest a permament solution, we will gladly use it ;)

Comment: yeah thats fixed the feed, although i'm kinda weary to include the access token in javascript since it's client facing and anyone can get in there and copy it down.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use my solution.
The solution is in PHP, but works :)

[Instagram workarond](https://github.com/Bolandish/Instagram-Hashtag-API)

Answer (score 0):

Using pixelunion seems to work but you may also need to add your user(s) via the Instagram developers page, through the Sandbox options if you're using Instafeed for anyone other than your own Instagram account.

Although the access tokens are not guaranteed to be 'forever', Instagram appears to be adding the disclaimer to protect itself against liability in case some change were needed in the future rather than actually stating that the generated tokens will definitely expire.